# Upgrade from 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.22 to PHP 5.6.0

Tags: upgrade, php

i have a problem and i want someone to help me, i have ubuntu server 14 and i have in my server php5 for installing owncloud, but, when i go to the page it says that i need to upgrade from 5.5.9 to at leats php.5.6.0 so i tried to put this

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip
php -v
```

but when i put sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php it says command not found,the if i try to put

```
sudo apt-get -y install php5.6 php5.6-mcrypt php5.6-mbstring php5.6-curl php5.6-cli php5.6-mysql php5.6-gd php5.6-intl php5.6-xsl php5.6-zip
```

Not found: and all the names of all what i puted. What could i do?

[Here a photo of what it says:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuPn5.png)

Answer (score 1):

to get the `add-apt-repository` command, you need to install software properties:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```